# How can i point pip to where my vstudio installation is?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, pip, package

Thank you in advance to anyone able to help.

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to install a package via pip that takes C++ build tools:

"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/%22)

Here is where vstudio is installed:

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools

I have the most current release of C++ build tools, which is what the error seems to be saying I don't have. I recently updated from a much older version of vstudio 2015 to the latest release, and I believe this has caused my issue.

Things I've tried:

1. updating pip
2. I read on another post to update setup tools for pip so I did "pip install --upgrade setuptools"
3. updating vstudio/vstudio C++ build tools
4. uninstall and reinstall vstudio/vstudio C++ build tools
5. I tested to see if I could recreate the issue on a different machine with the same versions of software and I was able to download a package like "mod-wsgi" that requires a C++ compiler successfully.

As I stated before I believe that the machine's pip I'm having this issue on is not pointing towards the right C++ build tools, but that's all I can figure out.

If I can provide anything else to help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where `pip` is installed then open a terminal (command prompt) there

then run this command `set VS150COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools` ( replace the path with the one of your Visual Studio )

then try installing again with `pip`, it should work.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the prompt response. I followed your directions of opening terminal and navigating to where pip is (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip). I then ran this command as per your direction:
set VS150COMNTOOLS=My path to\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools  and yet the issue persists

Comment: VS150COMNTOOLS could this command be for a specific version of build tools?

Comment: @J_Millar yes it an environment variable specific to Visual Studio 2017, You could also force to set the environment variables, otherwise I am not sure how to fix your problem.

Comment: how would I force set the environment variables?